# Deleting even numbers in Python list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to delete all the even numbers in the following list(2,4,6,8,10).  The code I have is throwing a "list index is out of range" error however.  Any ideas?

Thanks

```
names = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for idx in range( len(names) ):
    if names[idx] % 2 == 0:
        names.pop(idx)
```

Comment: Never alter a list while you are indexing over it!

Comment: The "pythonic" way to do this is `names = [e for e in names if e%2]`